# Mapping a convention center rooms on iOS

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

I am doing some research to see if this is even possible for an app I may begin work on soon.  One of the big features for this app is to add a map of a convention center where a camp will be held, allowing the user to see their current location in relative terms with the map.  I have an image of the interior of the convention center, but am unsure how much to scale the map is, and there are some issues with multiple stories in the building (as shown in the image below).  If I understand correctly, I can use the MapKit framework, plot out bounds for it, centered on a certain latitude and longitude point, and then add a Map Overlay with the image I have, and add some drop pins to the map for each room at their given latitude and longitudinal values?  I know I haven't shown any code in this question, I am simply working out the theory right now that my workflow in my mind is the more correct and best way to go about adding this functionality.  Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MapKnitter](http://mapknitter.org) to align your map and export as TMS, which is the format used in the MapTiles example from Apple and in their talk about MapViews with overlays.

You may find the GPS not accurate enough when inside a convention center to be 100% sure which room you're in, but if someone is standing at the wrong end of the center they'd know about it.